# sharing db connection across entire app in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With the latest mongoose update, you can no longer user models the way I've been doing. I need to share the same db connection across my entire app.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1249

Here is the old way which no longer works:

./models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), cfg = require('../config')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema
, db = mongoose.createConnection(cfg.mongo.uri, cfg.mongo.db);
...

module.exports = db.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

How can I re-use db connection as suggested in github issue above?

I'm using `var User = require('./models/user');` in several different places in my code base.

Answer (score 9):

### Option 1: Use a shared object

My model code looks similar, but instead of repeatedly requiring the modules I just require them once when the application starts and then assign the results to a shared object. For example if you are using an express app you could just so something like `app.locals.models.User = require('./models/user');`. Then anything with access to the `app` can see your models without needing a require.

---

### Option 2: Ensure a single modification in the exported function

You can define your user module like so:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String});

var User = null;

module.exports = function(db) {
  if (db && User === null) {
    User = db.model('User', userSchema);
  }
  return User;
};
```

When you start your application you simply need to: `require('./models/user')(db)`. Subsequent requires by other modules in your application can drop the `db` paramater, as `User` will only be set once.

Comment: i don't think that's what app.locals is supposed to be used for.

Comment: You can attach it to `app` instead of `app.locals` if it makes you feel better. :) Or you can attach it to a `foo` object and pass that in when you require your controller code (or whatever needs access to the models). The point is that you can avoid having to re-require the model files by using a common object to store the data.

Comment: @chovy I added a second option which you may find more appealing.

Comment: the only problem i see with this is now how do I get db connection from app.js into ./routes/login.js that calls ./models/user.js

Comment: Again, you only need to pass the db **once**. Have `app.js` or some database initialization module deal with that when the app starts. Later on when `./routes/login.js` needs the model, it can just `require('./models/user')` without the db parameter.

Comment: But i'm calling require('.models/user') from many different places. How do I not pass a db object?

Comment: I'm unclear where the confusion is. When I said once I meant for the life of the application. As long as you require with the `db` when the app starts, you no longer need to use the `db` parameter anywhere else in your app. You know you can call javascript functions without parameters right?

Comment: what if you wanted to share an exported object in your tests and also production code that your tests excercise?  Lets say I wanted to create a Context object with a property in it.  I want the test to set that property, and the code under test to also reference it so it uses whatever the test set for that property in its code too?