# Sharing a DB connection on the entire app or connect to DB on each request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing an API with **Nodejs** using **Restify**.
For the DB I'm using **Mongodb** (with **mongoose**).

I was wondering, what the best solution between sharing a db connection to my entire app or connecting to the db on each request ?

For now, I'm using the second option of this answer : [sharing db connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873430/sharing-db-connection-across-entire-app-in-mongoose/13874399#13874399)
But I've seen a different pattern here : [Node.js Web Application with Storage on MongoDB](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/website-with-mongodb-%28mac%29/)

I can't figure out, what is the best architecture ?
A list of pros and cons could be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course keeping one connection ( or pool of connections if mongoose supports it ) and reusing it is better, simply because creating connection on each request eats resources.

Comment: Yes, mongoose uses connection pooling ([default pool size is 5](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection_pools)).